# Varnish on Docker with Windows

Tags: bash, docker, varnish, varnish-vcl

everyone!

I'm using a Docker on Windows and I have a Docker file to provide a "varnish" installation and use, but when I run the docker compose I get an error on Varnish container and I don't know what I need do to fix that - the Varnish container is in restarting loop. This is the **docker file of Varnish:**

```
FROM 1and1internet/ubuntu-16

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install varnish -y 
RUN apt-get install nano -y

COPY default.vcl /etc/varnish/default.vcl

ENV VARNISH_START /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=varnish -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a 0.0.0.0:6081 -s malloc,1g

EXPOSE 6081

ADD start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

and the error is **(I get this on Docker container logs)**:

```
/init/entrypoint: /start.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

In **start.sh I have this code**:

```
#!/bin/bash

${VARNISH_START}
```

Someone can say me what I need do to fix that and run the Varnish container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^M` is the Carriage-Return character. You can see that the error is that it can't find `/bin/bash^M`

It looks like you've edited the `start.sh` with a tool like "Notepad" which has given it windows-style `CRLF` line endings (particularly to the shebang), rather than the linux-style `LF` which the container is expecting.

Using a 'proper' programming editor, such as Notepad++ or VSCode, you can change the line-endings to `LF` only. `dos2unix` on a linux system will also do this.

If you are using GIT for Windows, there's a chance that this is the culprit, as it messes with line-endings unless you tell it not to.

(You get to recognise `^M` when you've been bitten by this yourself a few times!)